# Como eu faço um Redirect no route caso seja a primeira vez que roda?

Tags: angularjs, route

Minha estrutura está assim:

```
var app = angular.module('MainApp',[
    'ngRoute',
    'mainAppControllers'
]);


app.config(['$routeProvider',

function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/tutorial', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/tutorial.html',
            controller:  'TutorialCtrl'
        }).
        when('/menu', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/menu.html',
            controller:  'MenuCtrl'
        }).
        when('/termo', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/termo_de_uso.html',
            controller:  'TermoCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/tutorial'
        }); 
}
]);
```

No entanto eu quero que quando for a primeira vez que abre o app ele direcione para uma página e se for a segunda vez que abre direciona para outra página.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Seu objetivo é criar algo como se fossem diversas etapas?

Comment: Oi @AndréRibeiro  minha ideia é na primeira vez que abrir o app ele levar para uma tela de tutorial e depois disso na segunda vez que abrir ele levar para outra tela. A tela de tutorial apareceria apenas na primeira vez q rodar o app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode armazenar uma entrada no `localStorage` assim que o controller do tutorial for carregado e na função `app.run()` do Angular você verifica se essa entrada existe e, caso *não* exista, você redireciona pra rota do tutorial.

A função `.run()` é chamada sempre na inicialização do módulo.

Ex.:

```
app.run(['$location', function($location){
  // tutorial foi visualizado? Se não (getItem() === null) redireciona pra rota do tutorial.
  if(window.localStorage.getItem("tutorial") === null) {
    $location.path('/tutorial');
  }
}]);
```

Ao carregar `TutorialController` a entrada é adicionada.

```
app.controller('TutorialCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    // ...
    window.localStorage.setItem("tutorial", 1);
    // ...
}]);
```

Lembrar de mudar a rota padrão pra algo que *não carregue* `TutorialCtrl`:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',

    function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/tutorial', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/tutorial.html',
                controller:  'TutorialCtrl'
            }).
            when('/menu', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/menu.html',
                controller:  'MenuCtrl'
            }).
            when('/termo', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/termo_de_uso.html',
                controller:  'TermoCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo : '/menu' // rota padrão que não seja a do tutorial
            }); 
    }
]);
```

Dessa forma o tutorial sempre será ser carregado na *primeira* vez que o app rodar independentemente da rota que for acessada. Nos carregamentos posteriores o funcionamento será normal.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente